# Как правильно дополнить объект с помощью jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

У меня есть такой json который я разбираю и делаю отрисовку страницы

```
{
    
    "user": "someuser",
    "message": "нужна помощь"
},
{
    "user": "Бот",
    "message": "чем могу помочь?"
},
{
    "user": "someuser",
    "message": "у меня другой вопрос"
}
```

Мне нужно  читать дополнительные параграфы на странице и дополнять ими мой json - обьект, для отправки на сервер. Позиций(сообщений) может быть около 10-20!
.edited-phrase и .phrase-return это то, что уже есть на странице в .client-mess и .bot-mess я заполняю данные из json.
Отправку ajax не проблема, проблема сформировать корректно данные(
Заранее спасибо!

[обновил код вопроса](https://jsfiddle.net/dezerter/xd3stzrn/14/)

Финальная версия должна выглядеть так:

```
    {
        "type": "text",
        "user": "someuser",
        "message": "нужна помощь",
        "edited": "помогите",
        "return": "вернуться шаг_1,
    },
    {
        "user": "Бот",
        "message": "чем могу помочь?"
    },
  {
        "user": "someuser",
        "message": "у меня другой вопрос"
        "edited": "передумал",
        "return": "вернуться шаг_3",
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно свойству переменной, содержащей этот объект, присваивать нужные Вам значения.
Наример
let k = {'t1': 'v1'};
k.t2 = 'v2';
По итогу имеем объект
k содержащий значение
{
't1': 'v1',
't2': 'v2'
}

Это просто по дополнению объекта.

Если вам нужно дополнять конкретные ПОДобъекты, то можно конвертировать исходный объект в массив значений, содержащих ПОДобъекты и работать по ключам этого массива.

Comment: как добавлять ключи в объекты я понимаю, все верно но как ничего не перепутать и все записать по порядку?
прогонять каждую строку в цикле и потом записывать как нужно?

Comment: Подвязывать ключи массива к вопросам

Comment: Можно ли на странице отследить порядковые индексы элементов, содержащих доп инфу о вопросах ? Они могли бы соответствовать индексам элеменов в массиве

Comment: как я это себе представляю, то вычитывать все элементы(к примеру с классом .edited-phrase)
добавлять их в новый массив  и потом по ключу добавлять как вы написали выше

Comment: я обновлю сейчас код на jsfiddle,но получается что сбивается очередность сообщений. Либо я что то делаю не так(

Comment: ПОпробуйте each применять для (".message-row") и уже внутри искать его индекс, доп информацию(типа edited-phrase) и использовать индекс message-row для соответствия индекса в массиве.

Comment: В данном случае вы инкрементируете count при переборе phrase, а вам нужно чтото вроде этого                                                                                             
  $('#sendJson').on('click', function() {
 $dialogMessages = {};
  var messagesArray = [];
  var editedQuestions = [];
    
    $(".container .message-row")
    .each(function (i,item) {
        editedQuestions.push($(this).find(".phrase").text());
       
    });